# Way to exit from the method

Tags: java

Is there any way to exit from the method? I hear that there are two way to exit.

**One :** throw Exception.

```
public void dosomething() {
    if(...) {
        throw new MyException();
    }
             // there might be another process.

}
```

**Two :** return somevalue. Even void method, we can return the value.

```
public void dosomething() {
    if(...) {
        return;
    }
             // there might be another process.
}
```

Question is, Is there any better way?

Comment: I think you answered your own question.

Comment: You've named two *excellent* ways to exit a method. What could possibly constitute a an *even better* way?

Comment: Void method will exit from method after executing last executable statement.

Comment: "is there any other way to exit from a method ?" is your question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you could `System.exit(int)` (the int value would be the value returned from the *process* and likely non-zero to indicate an error). It's a little brutal, however.

You can also interrupt yourself.

```
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
```

However:

1. this is still an exception. You're not throwing it explicitly, but it still results in an `InterruptedException`
2. your thread *has* to perform some IO/sleep operation subsequently to register this interruption. If it's solely computational then it won't exit due to this.

e.g. (note the `sleep()` to catch the interruption):

```
public class Test {
  public static void method() throws Exception {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("method done");
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    method();
    System.out.println("done");
  }
}
```

gives me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at T.method(T.java:5)
        at T.main(T.java:9)
```

Comment: what will be integer value for just method?

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR - yes, hence my 'brutal' comment

Comment: interrupt() method will not cause the thread to immediatelly cease execution.

Comment: @Jakub - my test suggests otherwise

Comment: @Jakub - or rather, it's not immediate but will trigger on the *next* IO/sleep. If it's solely compute-bound then it won't exit at all, I grant you

Comment: Read the javadoc for interrupt method. It merely sets the interrupted flag, which will cause InterruptedException be thrown if the thread is waiting for something. It will not return from the method per se.

Comment: Exactly. I didn't suggest it would. On the contrary I said there has to be some IO / sleep type interaction

Answer (score 1):

There is a third albeit not very useful way:

```
System.exit(0);
```

If you are asking this question for academic purposes...

The fact that you are throwing an Exception doesn't necessarily mean that you are exiting the method. For example if you do this:

```
try {
    throw  new Exception();
    // ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    // ...
}
```

you won't exit the method.

Additionally if you are calling a `void` method it will exit (implicit) after the last statement in the method body.

Comment: yeah but this exits the program not only the method

Comment: Is it exist the whole system?

Comment: but that would terminate the JVM itself. Op just want to get the hello outta the  method not his program :P

Comment: `System.exit(0);` exits the method too. He did not ask about side effects like program termination.

Comment: @AdamArold : correct , i was also thinking the same thing ,  thowing the exception doesn't exits your method

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Thread.currentThread().stop();
```

It will terminate the current thread without stopping the whole JVM.

BUT

`stop()` method is deprecated and inherently unsafe. From the specification:

> This method is inherently unsafe. Stopping a thread with Thread.stop
>   causes it to unlock all of the monitors that it has locked (as a
>   natural consequence of the unchecked ThreadDeath exception propagating
>   up the stack). If any of the objects previously protected by these
>   monitors were in an inconsistent state, the damaged objects become
>   visible to other threads, potentially resulting in arbitrary behavior.

So if you need to exit from a method and cannot `return` or throw an exeption, make the method run in its own thread and terminate this thread when necessary. Note this is not standard procedure, but more of a hack.

Comment: This isn't recommended just like `System.exit(0);`

Comment: @AdamArold Maybe, but it's a solution.

Comment: -1, don't give bad advice and certainly don't advice the use of deprecated methods that are documented with big warning signs not to use it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Informing is not same as advising.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You can treat this as an academic exercise (as most people answering here seem to do), but in my opinion people lacking in skill or knowledge will misinterpret these answers and construe an answer like this as advice and follow it up with all (potentially) negative consequences, instead of just using the perfectly reasonable and useful constructs already presented in the question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You have just written a useful comment; you have not justified the dowvnote, however. The answer dedicates 3/4 of its length to unsafety warnings.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I think my reasons stated above are enough. But if you want another one: it doesn't actually answer the question, as `Thread.stop()` doesn't just exit the current method, it stops the entire thread of execution.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Now it seems like you are inventing reasons on the fly just to have an excuse. OP didn't specify "just exit the current method". His own suggestion, throwing an exception, doesn't "just exit the current method", either.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - I think the provisos given in this answer are sufficient to alert people to the inherent dangers

Answer (score 0):

Can also this be consider ?

```
  public void test(){
             System.out.println("Do My work");
             String s = null;
             s.length();
             System.out.println("Do My  other work");

    }
```

Comment: It's the same as throwing na exeption. Nothing prevents you from firing your own NullPointerException.